# Baggage wait time

Tags: air-travel

How can I find out the time it took between landing and when the luggage finally arrived at the baggage claim area after a flight on AA in San Diego from 6 moths ago. Do they posts records when they drop off the flights luggage from the planes?

Comment: I don't think this is possible

Answer (score 4):

Currently, no, but as of June 2018, an International Air Transport Association (IATA) resolution on bag tracking will change that, as explained in [SITA's Baggage Report for the industry](http://comms.sita.aero/rs/089-ZSE-857/images/baggage-report-2017.pdf)

> Under IATA’s Resolution 753, airlines must demonstrate delivery or acquisition of baggage when custody changes; provide an inventory of bags upon departure of a flight; and be capable of exchanging this information with other airlines ortheir agents as needed.
>
> There are four mandatory tracking points at which the bag, via its unique 10-digit bag-tag number, must be recorded: at check-in, when the passenger gives their bag to the airline; loading, when the bag is delivered onto the aircraft; transfer, when custody of the bag changes between carriers; and finally, at arrival, when the bag is delivered back to the passenger.

However, a number of carriers, including [American Airlines](https://www.aa.com/i18n/travel-info/travel-tools/american-airlines-app.jsp), have a web and/or mobile app to allow customers to track their bags. You would have to contact AA to know whether any information is still available, and whether it includes arrival-to-carousel timing.

Answer (score 0):

American Airlines mobile app has a feature to track your bags. It allows you to see the baggage counter where you can collect the bag, which essentially indicates that your bag has reached the counter. However, it does not show estimated time or whatsoever. Hope this information helps.